# Is LINQ leveraging database index to execute this query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In addition to the `ID` attribute, I am setting EntityFramework to index the `Name` attribute of my model:

```
public class EntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Student>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Student> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Students");
        builder.HasKey(obi => obi.ID);
        builder.Property(obj => obj.ID).IsRequired(true);
        builder.HasIndex(obj => obj.Name).IsUnique();
    }
}
```

Then at some point in my code, I query for students by their name:

```
var student = dbContext.Students.First(x => x.Name == "Meryl");
```

This query is executed thousands of times, and I have millions of `Student`s in database. Hence, its performance is critical, but currently it runs very slow, so I am not sure if LINQ is actually leveraging the database index.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try running [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/start-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15), which will allow you to capture the query that is generated by LINQ and view the query plan.

Comment: Is there actually an index on that column, in the DB? (I want to know if you have actually migrated the db and caused the index to be created)

Comment: The only way to really know what is happening in any ORM or linqtoswl, its to look at the resulting query plan of the generated sql

Comment: Please use Management Studio to generate the existing CREATE TABLE script of your existing table (including indexes) and include that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

*HasIndex* is used to instruct EF to create an index on the the column(s) when EF is used in Code-First manner (i.e. use the object model to create the database schema). Otherwise it has no effect.

To speed up queries, you should make sure the index in the database is configured correctly (e.g. have an index on the Name column) and that the queries generated by EF are performant.